Automatically display the first bullet point in an incremental list
I would like the first bullet point to be automatically displayed when using an incremental list in a revealjs presentation in Quarto.
---
title: "My Presentation"
format: revealjs 
---

## Example slide

::: {.incremental}
- This should automatically appear
- This should appear after advancing the slide
:::


I know this could be handled using .fragment or excluding the first line from the .incremental div, but these solutions add a space between the bullet points due to the required line break before a div (see discussion here ).
